# Loading Maya model with Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, webgl, maya

I am following [this](http://www.samwirch.com/blog/viewing-models-maya-webgl-threejs) tutorial on how to load Maya models with Three.js.

Everything is fine, but tutorial only explains how to load models with one texture.

Here's the source code from the tutorial:

```
function createScene(geometry, x, y, z, scale, tmap) {
            zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tmap)}));
            zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
            zmesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
            meshes.push(zmesh);
            scene.add(zmesh);
        }
```

Full JS [Live Link](http://freeeggsinbasket.com/tahmid/3d/index.html)

```
            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
        var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

        var container;

        var camera, scene;
        var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;

        var mesh, zmesh, geometry, materials;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        var meshes = [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000);
            camera.position.x = 400;
            camera.position.y = 200;
            camera.position.z = 400;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            // LIGHTS
            var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);
            scene.add(ambient);

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
            directionalLight.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
            scene.add(directionalLight);

            // RENDERER
            webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
            webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";

            container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
                callbackKey = function (geometry, materials) {
                    createScene(geometry, materials, 0, 0, 0, 6);
                };
            loader.load("chameleon.js", callbackKey);

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }

        function createScene(geometry, materials, x, y, z, scale) {


            zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
            zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
            zmesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
            meshes.push(zmesh);
            scene.add(zmesh);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        function animate() {
            for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
                meshes[i].rotation.y += 0.01;
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
```

But my model has four textures. What should I change to load all of them?[Live Link](http://freeeggsinbasket.com/tahmid/3d/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it appears the tutorial your following is ignoring the materials from the JSON model format and simply passing the geometry and a straight text reference to a single texture file like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
    callbackKey = function(geometry) {createScene(geometry,  0, 0, 0, 15, "chameleon.jpg")};
loader.load("chameleon.js", callbackKey);
```

The JSONLoader not only pulls in the geometry but all the materials in an array. (see: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js line 45) You can then pass this array to the MeshFaceMaterial(**arrayOfMaterials**) like so:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();,
    callbackKey = function(geometry, materials) {createScene(geometry, materials, 0, 0, 0, 15, )};
loader.load("chameleon.js", callbackKey);
```

Then in your createScene function you change the first line to be:

```
zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
```

Edit: Adding details on fixing Maya exports

So your model is loading but black. In this case the issue is in the model file `chameleon.js`. Have a look at each material's `colorAmbient` and `colorDiffuse` property. Notice they're all [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]. This is a known obj export bug in Maya. So you have 3 options to fix it.

1) Open the `chameleon.js` file and alter all the `colorAmbient` and `colorDiffuse` lines to something like this (you'll need to play with the values to make it look right)

```
"colorAmbient" : [0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
"colorDiffuse" : [0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
```

OR

2) In Maya before applying your diffuse map, always make sure to apply a default color value first. For some reason once the map is on you can no longer access the color property and the exporter uses the default value of 0.

OR

3) After exporting from Maya you can alter the OBJ file by change these lines from:

```
Kd 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

To

```
Kd 0.80 0.80 0.80
```

I've tested this here at home and your model is looking good, let me know how it goes?

Comment: #Darryl_Lehmann [Live Link](http://freeeggsinbasket.com/tahmid/3d/index.html). i have done what you suggested me to do. but no texture on model but only black color. did i miss something ? please help!

Comment: Not to worry, it is working correctly. Have a look at my edited answer to see how to fix the model file to display correctly.

Comment: #Darryl_Lehmann is there anyway i can change cloth's of that model?

Comment: Yes, it depends on your end goal, but yes. If you just want to alter the fabric's color, then change the related textures. If you'd like to change the entire outfit, then some 3D modelling skills will come into play. Otherwise, you can alter the geometry vertex by vertex in code, but at a considerable performance hit each time (altering geometry causes a dump and rebuild of the model's entire stored structure). Hope the helps.

Comment: i would like to change textures. i dont want to change the whole model only the textures. can u give me some example link ?
[my problem's link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18692891/how-to-change-one-texture-image-of-a-3d-modelmaya-in-three-js-at-runtime)

Comment: @Darryl_Lehmann i was going through your solution for adding multiple images but i am getting some error "cannot read property map of undefined"

is the below way proper to add materials
materials.push( new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "js/wall.jpg" ) } ) );