# How to change one texture image of a 3d model(maya ) in three.js at runtime

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, three.js, webgl, maya

[This site](http://freeeggsinbasket.com/tahmid/3d/index.html) is loading a maya model using three.js.
This model has Below texture pictures

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is the JS

```
 var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

 var container;

 var camera, scene;
 var canvasRenderer, webglRenderer;

 var mesh, zmesh, geometry, materials;

 var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
 var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

 var meshes = [];

 function init() {

     container = document.createElement('div');
     document.body.appendChild(container);

     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 100000);
     camera.position.x = 400;
     camera.position.y = 200;
     camera.position.z = 400;

     scene = new THREE.Scene();

     // LIGHTS
     var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x666666);
     scene.add(ambient);

     var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffeedd);
     directionalLight.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
     scene.add(directionalLight);

     // RENDERER
     webglRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     webglRenderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
     webglRenderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";

     container.appendChild(webglRenderer.domElement);

     var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
         callbackKey = function (geometry, materials) {
             createScene(geometry, materials, 0, 0, 0, 6)
         };
     loader.load("chameleon.js", callbackKey);

     window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

 }

 function createScene(geometry, materials, x, y, z, scale) {

     zmesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
     zmesh.position.set(x, y, z);
     zmesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
     meshes.push(zmesh);
     scene.add(zmesh);
 }

 function onWindowResize() {

     windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
     windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

     camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
     camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

     webglRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 }

 function animate() {
     for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
         meshes[i].rotation.y += .01;
     }
     requestAnimationFrame(animate);
     render();
 }

 function render() {
     camera.lookAt(scene.position);
     webglRenderer.render(scene, camera);
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     init();
     animate();
 });
```

now i want to change the 1st texture picture  to some other texture and rest of the texture remains same on runtime! how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you'd like to change the texture at runtime. All you need to do is look at the zmesh objects material. Find the appropriate index of the blue dress material and swap it out. Your model is a little tricky in that you have an array of materials but no matter. For a single material object you simply change the `mesh.material.map` and update it, in your case we need `mesh.material.materials[index].map`. So try adding this to the bottom of your `createScene` function. It will replace the dress with the eyeball texture:

```
zmesh.material.materials[1].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'c006_10.jpg' );
```

Of course, replace 'c006_10.jpg' with the appropriate path to your eyeball texture. One added Note, if you hook up the texture swap to an `onclick` for example you'll want to have an active render loop or call renderer's render function to get it to display.

Comment: `loadTexture` sets the `texture.needsUpdate` flag on the texture. Do not set it yourself when calling this function. Do not set `material.needsUpdate` either. That builds a new shader program.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the clarification. Going to go optimize a few projects I'm working on Thanks WestLangley! Editing the answer now.

Comment: @Darryl_Lehmann @WestLangley Works like dream. Thank you very much. it worked perfectly. one thing i would like to know. i need an image variable to feed as my texture, so i did this
               ` var tempimage = new Image();
                tempimage.onload = function () {
                   
                    zmesh.material.materials[0].map = new THREE.Texture(tempimage);
 zmesh.material.materials[0].map.needsUpdate = true; // if i delete this line every goes black!


                };
  tempimage.src = "Soundwave/RB_Soundwave_Norm_XY_1024.png";`
it works. am i doing the right coding?

Comment: Indeed, simply creating a THREE.Texture won't call an update, so you do need to do so manually. If you were to use the THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture approach that update call is handled automoatically for you. Have a peak at the ImageUtils.js [link](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/ad419d40bdaab80abbb34b8f359b4ee840033a02/src/extras/ImageUtils.js) file for reference.